# jquery dataTable create Click Event on row click

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there any other way to create a click event on row of data table aside from this.

```
$('#accledger-table1 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table1.row(this).data();
    console.log(data);
} );
```

That code is working when I display my table for the first time. But when i tried to clear the table and add another set of data. The row that click get the data of the last set of data that i clear.

this is how i add the data to table.

```
 var table1 = $('#accledger-table1').DataTable({
    "sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>',
    columns: [
    { data: "1" },
    { data: "2", },
    { data: "3" },
    { data: "4" },
    { data: "5" },
    { data: "6" },
    { data: "7" },
    { data: "8" },
    { data: "9" },
    { data: "10" },
    { data: "11" },
    { data: "12" },
    { data: "13" }
    ],
    destroy: true,
    sort: false,
});

table1.clear().draw();
for (var i = 0; i <= RetObject.ACC_LEDGER.length - 1; i++) {
    var ledger = RetObject.ACC_LEDGER[i];
    table1.rows.add([{
        "1": ledger.1,
        "2": ledger.2,
        "3": ledger.3,
        "4": ledger.4,
        "5": ledger.5,
        "6": ledger.6,
        "7": numberWithCommas(ledger.7),
        "8": numberWithCommas(ledger.8),
        "9": numberWithCommas(ledger.9),
        "10": numberWithCommas(ledger.10),
        "11": numberWithCommas(ledger.11),
        "12": numberWithCommas(ledger.12),
        "13": ledger.REMARKS,
    }]).draw(false);

}
```

Comment: u need to something like that for a dynamic generated element, `$(document).('click', '#accledger-table1 tbody tr', function(){});`

Comment: After you add new rows you will need to re-add the click event to the tr's. Vue would handle this decently well and can be used without a javascript build tool, i'd suggest taking a look.

Comment: what do you mean Vue? do i need to switch to vue data tables which i can't.

Comment: @Se0ng11 have the answer, this is because you are redraw (recreate dom), so you need to find parent of `#accledger-table1` , or simply use `document` as selector